# how to iterate *ngFor through Different objects in array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I have dynamically generated inconsistent array of Objects from API(server).

E.g:

```
array = [
 {name: 'blah', age:2},
 {status: 'pending', date: '20-20-2020'},
 {blah: 'foo', google: 'bar'},
 {apple: 'android', microsoft: 'eeewww'}
]
```

this array could be anything with different keys and values.

> how can i Iterate through it to show the values in `ngFor`?

What I am currently is doing:

```
this.printArray = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this.array), null, 4);

<div *ngFor="let print of printArray">
  {{print}}  // it prints the array like {"name": blah, "age": 2} but i don't want it in this way
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please let us know what output you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Angular keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

```
<div *ngFor="let element of myArray"> 
    <!--element is an object-->
    <div *ngFor="let item of element|keyvalue">
        {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is Interesting. i will look into it. Thanks.